# Junit Test cases for PubSub Publish message

Tags: java, junit4, google-cloud-pubsub

Facing issue while writing the Junit test cases for below code.

```
public String publishJSON(String json) throws InterruptedException, IOException, ExecutionException {             
        log.info(" Publishing payload to: "+config.getTopicId());   
        TopicName topicName=TopicName.of(config.getPubsubProjectId(),config.getTopicId());
        Publisher publisher=null;
        try {
             publisher =
                    Publisher.newBuilder(topicName)
                        .build();
              ByteString data = ByteString.copyFromUtf8(json);
              PubsubMessage pubsubMessage = PubsubMessage.newBuilder().setData(data).build();
              ApiFuture<String> messageIdFuture = publisher.publish(pubsubMessage);
              String messageId = messageIdFuture.get();
              log.info("Published message ID: " + messageId);
           return messageId;
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            log.error("Error while publishing messsage" + e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error( "PubSub exception "+ e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            log.error("Connection making exception for PubSub" + e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error( "publishJSON Error : "+ e.getMessage());
            throw e;    
        }
        finally {
            if (publisher != null) {
                // When finished with the publisher, shutdown to free up resources.
                publisher.shutdown();
                publisher.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does "*Facing issue*" mean? Do you get a compilation error? If so: please [edit] the post, add the compiler error and highlight the line of code causing the compilation error. Does it throw an exception? If so: please [edit] the post, add the stack trace and highlight the line of code causing the exception. Do you observe unexpected behaviour? If so: please [edit] the post, add a [MRE], as we as expected and observed output.

Comment: I am unable to write Junit test case for the above method. Need help how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but just trying to explain the problem.
You cannot Mock Publisher.Builder class
as a result, any actions that happen further in the chain of calls to Publisher, Publisher.Builder, PubsubMessage.publish methods cannot be mocked.

Is that the reason for "unable to write test case"?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).